# I get an error "Validation of viewstate MAC failed

Tags: c#, load-balancing

Our setup is such that this is through Load balanced sticky sessions. When I use only one server I don't get this error at all. When I use the Load balancer, I get this error sporadically. How can I make this error go away when I use Load balancer

my config file says :

```
<machineKey validationKey='2EEA416CEFC6D6BE856ED57B97FB9CA7DFACE17C073125949A1D682C80A44BB2AD887DDDC13DBFB0954F1000FEE5757E99693F222F8E28CAA2E6DAB8C4F99E0C'
    decryptionKey='877478B2F33A74226ABEF55FDCC1A76E43F1BBEA6241A592'
    validation='SHA1' />
<pages enableViewStateMac="false">
    <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit"/>
    </controls>
</pages>
```

I've already used `enableViewStateMac="false">`. Plus the challenge is to erase sporadic errors with load balancer. What approach can I take?